# Punctuating a very complicated sentence

Tags: commas

> They reached the island with an airplane (,)and (,) realizing that no
>   damage was done to them (,) were happy, since they had finished their
>   journey.

I know there has to be a comma somewhere in the sentence, but I just cannot determine it. Where is the comma needed in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

> They reached the island with an airplane (,)and (,) realizing that no damage was done to them (,) were happy, since they had finished their journey.

Your original is not entirely idiomatic. If we make a couple of vocabulary changes then the sentence becomes easier to read and punctuate.

> They reached the island by airplane and, realizing that no damage was done to them,  were happy because they had finished their journey.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the comma before *and* is not necessary. Boil it down: you wouldn't use a comma before *and* in this shorter sentence:

> I went to the store and bought some milk.

So it also doesn't belong here:

> I went to the store and, realizing I was thirsty, bought some milk.

Comment: So basically does this sentence work like this? I went to the store and, to quench my thirst, bought some milk. But the problem is, you can delete the comma before "to quench my thirst" like this: I went to the store and to quench my thirst, bought some milk. So why can I not do the same with your sentence like this? :  I went to the store and realizing I was thirsty, bought some milk.

Comment: @jose: Your assertion that 'you can delete the comma before "to quench my thirst" like this: I went to the store and to quench my thirst, bought some milk.' is by no means obviously true. Arguably you could get away with removing the comma after _thirst_ (thereby leaving the sentence with zero commas), but in my opinion the sentence is wrongly punctuated with the single comma after _thirst_. Like Angela (I assume),  I would punctuate your counterexample this way: 'you can delete the comma before "to quench my thirst" like this: I went to the store and, to quench my thirst, bought some milk.'

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should put in *all* the commas you've enclosed in parentheses.

Also, "since they have finished" should probably be "since they had finished".

Comment: Can you explain why I have to put all of them?

Comment: Because I thought the comma before "and" was not necessary as in this sentence: I had nice time and on the beach, drank some beer.

Comment: I suppose you could make that case.  I recommended including it because I was interpreting it as a compound sentence, and a comma goes before the conjunction in a [compound sentence](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/compound-sentence-examples.html). But since "they" is the subject of both clauses, and since the subject only appears in the first clause, you could alternatively say that it's a _simple_ sentence with a [compound _predicate_](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/compound_predicate.htm), which _doesn't_ require a comma.  To me, it looks/sounds strange without it, though.